# Minify alternative pure php, (Assetic, Grunt, ?)

Tags: gruntjs, minify, assetic

i am building a website with Cakephp Framework and Bootstrap 3 for GUI. Currently i use Minify 2.1.7 to combine and minify css and js files. 
When i started playing with the idea to use Bootstraps's less files for more flexibility and cleaner css code i researched more information about Minify in order to combine it with a less parser. Unfortunately i found out that Minify is said to be a great security risk and should not be used. People recommend grunt or assetic instead. Both tools are very complicated to use and afaik they are not php only but also require certain binary support for parsers etc.

1. Is there a way to or a php-tool like Minify that can combine, minify and and parse less?
2. Is there a way to use gruntjs, assetic or other tools for my usecase? (php only)
3. Is Minify really such a security issue?

Answer (score 1):

1. There are grunt tasks for minify and compiling most assets, here is one for [less grunt-contrib-less](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-less).
2. Grunt can be used with servers written in any language, use it to generate your static assets and serve them with whatever language you want

Comment: but it does not work "on-the-fly" aka i edit a css file with my IDE that uploads it via ftp and when i open the website in my browser the files get served combined, less parsed etc?

Comment: You can use [grunt-contrib-watch](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-watch) to watch your css files and run the [grunt-contrib-ftpush](https://github.com/inossidabile/grunt-contrib-ftpush) task to deploy it over ftp